# Как объяснить постановку запятой в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

*Он стал присматриваться, как катаются другие.* Как здесь объяснить постановку запятой?

Comment: Необъяснимо отсутствие пробела.

Answer (score 4):

*Он стал присматриваться, как катаются другие.* Запятая здесь нужна, поскольку **как катаются другие** является изъяснительным придаточным предложением, присоединённым к главному предложению с помощью союзного слова **как**.

Comment: Матвей, а может быть, КАК ― это союзное слово?

Comment: А почему не союз, Sibylla?

Comment: У изъяснительных придаточных есть два подтипа: союзный и относительный (местоименный). Союз КАК употребляется при опорных словах со значением восприятия, ощущения, например: Было слышно, как дождь стучит по крыше. Фактически он синонимичен союзу ЧТО, но имеет дополнительное значение достоверности: Я видел, как (что) белка перепрыгивает с ветки на ветку.  В нашем случае такую замену не сделаешь, и значение у местоимения КАК - это КАКИМ ОБРАЗОМ.

Comment: Понял, исправлю. Благодарю, Sibylla!

Comment: Спасибо, Сибилла, и я узнал кое-что новое!